# Dataframe filtering based on condition in YAML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I'm trying to filter dataframe by conditions stored in YAML. There are probably 100+ conditions to filter; these are just some of the conditions.

Sample dataframe:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   5   21  3
1   1   5   21  2
2   1   5   21  2
3   1   5   21  3
4   1   5   21  3
5   2   103 20  8
6   2   2   20  6
7   2   103 20  9
8   2   101 20  7
9   2   101 20  7
```

Yaml file:

```
general_1:
  condition_1:
    'A': 1
    'B': 5
    'C': range(0, 8)
    'D': 21

  condition_2:
    'A': 1
    'B': 4
    'C': range(9, 200)
    'D': 22

  condition_3:
    'A': 1
    'B': 3
    'C': range(3, 200)
    'D': 22

    condition_4:
    'A': 1
    'B': 6
    'C': range(3, 200)
    'D': [21, 101, 102, 241, 242, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 665, 667, 767, 861, 862]
```

My aim are to match this condition to the dataframe and create new column containing the results so i can flag the unmatched row.

## Define the path to the input CSV file

```
input_file = data_file
```

## Define the path to the configuration YAML file

```
config_file = yaml_file

def filter_columns(df, yaml_file):
    with open(yaml_file) as f:
        config = yaml.safe_load(f)
    for row in df:
        if (row['A'] == config['general_1']['condition_1']['A'] and
            row['B'] == config['general_1']['condition_1']['B'] and
            row['C'] == config['general_1']['condition_1']['C'] and
            row['D'] in config['general_1']['condition_1']['D']):
            row['matched'] = 1
        elif (row['A'] == config['general_1']['condition_2']['A'] and
              row['B'] == config['general_1']['condition_2']['B'] and
              row['C'] == config['general_1']['condition_2']['C'] and
              row['D'] in config['general_1']['condition_2']['D']):
            row['matched'] = 1
        elif (row['A'] == config['general_1']['condition_3']['A'] and
              row['B'] == config['general_1']['condition_3']['B'] and
              row['C'] == config['general_1']['condition_3']['C'] and
              row['D'] in config['general_1']['condition_3']['D']):
            row['matched'] = 1
        else:
            row['matched'] = 0
    return df
```

## Read the input CSV file into a list of dictionaries

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = [row for row in reader]
```

## Filter the columns based on the configuration file

```
filtered_data = filter_columns(data, config_file)
```

I don't know where i've done wrong. The function does not create the new column containing the results.

Comment: What does your CSV file look like?

Comment: I've got an entire dataset and the average rows are 3000+ and 140 columns, but some CSV got more than 10000 rows.

Comment: Is the "D" value of each condition a list or integer? or can it be both? In your example "D" of condition 4 is a list but others are integer

Comment: It can be both, but it should be a string not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution should give you the result you're looking for. The yaml data is converted to pandas dataframe and then you can compare the 2 dataframes.

**Convert YAML data to DataFrame**

```
df_yaml = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [(k, k1, k2, v2) for k, v in config.items() for k1, v1 in v.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items() ],
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
)
df_yaml = df_yaml.pivot(index=['A', 'B'], columns='C', values='D')
df_yaml.index = df_yaml.index.set_names(['general', 'condition'])
df_yaml = df_yaml.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df_yaml["C"] = df_yaml["C"].apply(lambda x: eval(x))
df_yaml["D"] = df_yaml["D"].apply(lambda x: [x] if not isinstance(x, list) else x)
df_yaml = df_yaml.explode('C')
df_yaml = df_yaml.explode('D')
```

`df_yaml` looks like this before the explode:

```
                       A  B                        C                              D
general   condition                                                       
general_1 condition_1  1  5      (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...)                            [3]
          condition_2  1  4  (9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ...)                           [22]
          condition_3  1  3      (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...)                           [22]
          condition_4  1  6      (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...)  [21, 101, 102, 241, 242, ...]
```

After `explode` each element of `C` and `D` is converted to a row and will look like this:

```
                       A  B    C    D
general   condition                  
general_1 condition_1  1  5    0    3
          condition_1  1  5    1    3
          condition_1  1  5    2    3
          condition_1  1  5    3    3
          condition_1  1  5    4    3
...                   .. ..  ...  ...
          condition_4  1  6  199  102
          condition_4  1  6  199  241
          condition_4  1  6  199  242
          condition_4  1  6  199  341
          condition_4  1  6  199  862
```

Now you can compare if each row from `df` matches the corresponding column and row value from `df_yaml`

```
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: df_yaml[
        (df_yaml['A'] == x['A']) &
        (df_yaml['B'] == x['B']) &
        (df_yaml['C'] == x['C']) &
        (df_yaml['D'] == x['D'])
    ].shape[0] > 0, axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
   A    B   C  D  match
0  1    5  21  3   True
1  1    5  21  2  False
2  1    5  21  2  False
3  1    5  21  3   True
4  1    5  21  3   True
5  2  103  20  8  False
6  2    2  20  6  False
7  2  103  20  9  False
8  2  101  20  7  False
9  2  101  20  7  False
```